# CKEditor 5: Adding the table feature into classic-build fails

Tags: jquery, webpack, ckeditor, ckeditor5, webpack-encore

I am using CKEditor 5, classic editor, i want to add the table feature in the toolbar, I use webpack to manage dependencies, here is my code:

```
   import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor";   
   import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table';
   import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar';


   $('.ckEditorArea').each(function () {

   ClassicEditor
        .create(this, {
            plugins: [ Table, TableToolbar ],
            toolbar: ['insertTable' ],
            table: {
                toolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells' ]
            }
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error.stack );
        } );
  )};
```

I added the package with:

```
    npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-table
```

then I rebuild my project:

```
npm run build
```

I have this error in the navigator console:

```
add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:71541 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
at IconView._updateXMLContent (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:46548)
at IconView.render (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:46524)
at IconView.on (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:62581)
at IconView.fire (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:57769)
at IconView.(anonymous function) [as render] (http://localhost:9027/build/js/add-edit/add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:62585:16)
at ViewCollection.on (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:21922)
at ViewCollection.fire (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:57769)
at ViewCollection.add (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:514)
at DropdownButtonView.render (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:45244)
at DropdownButtonView.render (add-test.3649361ad73210f1e631.js:61776)
```

and this when I execute the command

```
npm run build
```

Result:

```
error

js/add-test.9ba3edd31c9f973445cd.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (i) [js/add-test.9ba3edd31c9f973445cd.js:380,14
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You must not add plugins to an existing build. You can only add plugins to a source editor (mind `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic` vs `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic` difference). Please refer to [Installing plugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) and to a very similar question asked recently: [ckeditor5 & CakePHP 2.3: How do I make the tables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642343/ckeditor5-cakephp-2-3-how-do-i-make-the-tables-work)
2. Your setup seems to be using an old version of UglifyJS which is only able to minify ES5. CKEditor 5 is built in ES6 and requires an ES6-compatible minifier or transpiling its source to ES5 via Babel. If you'd use webpack 4+ and its builtin "production mode" which uses `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` all would fine out of the box because that plugin uses a ES6-compatible version of UglifyJS. You can find more information about it in [the CKEditor 5 Framework's Quick start](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html) guide. But in general, the problem would not occur if you'd follow the [Installing plugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) guide.