# ckeditor5 & CakePHP 2.3: How do I make the tables work?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, ckeditor, cakephp-2.3, ckeditor5

I have a CakePHP 2.3 app that for years has had whatever version CK Editor.

I'm working in developing mode, hoping to upgrade it to CKEditor 5.

I easily and quickly got rid of all old code and files to make ckeditor5 work just fine in its most basic version.

This was a go!

However, I do need tables. I'm now working on getting the table feature set up and just cannot get it working.

Here's their doc on this:
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/features/table.html

`npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-table` has run successfully. The files are in my repo.

However, the `import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table';` and `import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar';` statements make things break.

I have tried moving the `@ckeditor` folder out of the main project and into the app's `app/webroot/js` folder.

I have tried calling the scripts in different ways.

I am currently trying to figure out if `require.js` is the answer for loading these modules, but can't seem to understand how to make it all come together.

**Basically, the big question is:**

For CakePHP 2.3 specifically,

where should the `@ckeditor` folder be

and how do those files/modules get imported into Views

without generating

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
or
`Uncaught Error: Module name 'Table' has not been loaded yet for context:`

errors?

**And a little question:**

Has anyone put out content on how to get the **CKEditor 5** working **with its table feature** in a **CakePHP** app, yet? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: To me this reads as if it's unrelated to CakePHP, as building CKE is basically always the same, and the generated JS can be included like any other JS. You'll have to make yourself familiar with [**custom builds**](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html), [**compiling from source**](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html), [**installing plugins**](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html), and maybe also with [**webpack**](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sent me down the right path. I eventually got it. webpack was a much better train of thought than require.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm)'s answer led me to look into `webpack` closely. I knew nothing about. It was much more suited for this job than `require.js`.

I must say that I still don't understand all of the inner workings of each thing below, but I got the ckeditor 5 working with tables, as needed.

I had to:

1. install Node.js
2. install npm
3. do a local ckeditor 5 build (I had hoped to stick with CDN) - [link here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installation.html#npm)
4. do a plugin install with the table plugin - [link for plugin install here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) and [link for table plugin directions
   here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/table.html#installation)
5. Set toolbars and other settings in the `src/ckeditor.js` file itself before running `npm run build`. I could not get it working from the `HTML`, because I could not get `js` to recognize the names and classes. I kept getting `Unexpected identifier` errors until I just gave up and called it directly from `src/ckeditor.js`. This is fine for my case, because all of my app's **CK Editor** boxes can be the same. If you need variation, I'm not sure how to make that work.

Finally, I should point out that for all of my command line actions, I worked directly from `CakePHP`'s `app/webroot/js` directory, so things were installed in such a way that in the end, my script call is:
`<script src="/js/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js"></script>`, so my code for creating the box is:

```
<textarea id="my_dear_ckeditor5_textarea"></textarea>

<!-- ckeditor.js built by following steps 1 thru 5 above -->
<script src="/js/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#my_dear_ckeditor5_textarea' ) )
    .catch( error => {} );

});
</script>
```

If someone needs this reference, here's EXACTLY what my `src/ckeditor.js` looks like:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2018, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md.
 */

// The editor creator to use.
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar';

export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

// Plugins to include in the build.
ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    Essentials,
    UploadAdapter,
    Autoformat,
    Bold,
    Italic,
    BlockQuote,
    Heading,
    Link,
    List,
    Paragraph,
    Alignment,
    Table,
    TableToolbar
];

// Editor configuration.
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'alignment',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            '|',
            'link',
            '|',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'blockQuote',
            '|',
            'insertTable',
            '|',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    },
    heading: {
        options: [
        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'parágrafo normal', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Título 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Título 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
        { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Título 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
        { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Título 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
        { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Título 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
        { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Título 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' },
        { model: 'heading7', view: 'h7', title: 'Título 7', class: 'ck-heading_heading7' }
            ]
    },
  table: {
      toolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells' ]
  },
    language: 'pt-br'
};
```